# The use of "dementsprechend"

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I'm a bit confused by the word *dementsprechend* in the following sentence.

> Infolge von hohen Kosten kann man leider nicht dementsprechend viel herstellen.

I found out that it means *accordingly* and so I understand it's function in the sentence. But is it really necessary? Or can the sentence be stated without it and keeps its meaning?

Comment: It seems that "dementsprechend" refers to an entity in a previous sentence. The situation is different if the sentence read "... leider dementsprechend nicht viel herstellen" or "... leider nicht, dementsprechend, viel herstellen" - in those cases, the word would IMHO refer to "hohe Kosten" and would be, *dementsprechend*, redundant.

Comment: "dementsprechend viel" is a fixed phrase meaning "as much as". Hint: the verb "entsprechen" means "to follow a wish/command" or simply "to accord".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*dementsprechend* and *infolge* might be, depending on context, somewhat redundant in your example sentence.

The literal translation is, as you say, "accordingly", but *dementsprechend* is often used in a causal connotation and can simply be translated to "thus".

> Er war müde und dementsprechend schlecht gelaunt.
>
> He was tired and thus in a bad temper.

In case the sentence is embedded in more context like

> Der Bedarf an Goldmünzen ist in den letzten Jahren sehr gestiegen - Infolge von hohen Kosten kann man aber leider nicht dementsprechend viel herstellen.
>
> The demand for gold coins has increased a lot during the last years - but, because of high cost, production can not keep up [with that demand].

the *dementsprechend* would relate to the high demand in the previous sentence in a connotation of "as mentioned before" and **not** be redundant.